# Report multiline query results as a single line

Tags: sql

My current SQL query

```
Select TransactionId,Variable,
case when Variable = '%ForeignPrice' then VarNumericValue  end AS [Foreign Price],
 case when Variable = '%PrevForeignPrice' then VarNumericValue  end AS [Previous Foreign Price],
case when Variable = '%PrevPrice' then VarNumericValue  end AS [Previous Price],
 case when Variable = '%Price' then VarNumericValue  end AS [Price],
 case when Variable = '%PurchaseOrder' then VarAlphaValue  end AS [Purchase Order],
 case when Variable = '%PurchaseOrderLine' then VarNumericValue  end AS [Purchase Order Line],
 case when Variable = '%StockCode' then VarAlphaValue  end AS [Stock Code]
   from AdmSignatureLogDet where Variable <> '%Key' and TransactionId = 250204
```

gives the following result
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMwQf.png)

How do I get the result so that all the values appear on a single line with the NULL values removed? The column Variable is not needed in the final query but is included to show where the data originated.

Comment: And how do the results look if you remove column 2 from your query.

Comment: Looks exactly the same except without column 2 since I need to refer to that column in the case statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each of your case expressions with a `SUM()` function and then group by transaction_id.

```
create table my_data (
  transactionid integer, 
  variable varchar(50), 
  VarNumericValue integer
  );
  
insert into my_data values 
(1, '%ForeignPrice', 100), 
(1, '%PrevForeignPrice', 90);
```

---

```
select transactionid, 
 sum(case when variable = '%ForeignPrice' then VarNumericValue end) as foreign_price, 
 sum(case when variable = '%PrevForeignPrice' then VarNumericValue end) as previous_foreign_price 
from my_data
group by transactionid;
```

| transactionid | foreign_price | previous_foreign_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 90 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4KntXgUSbAZrf2BpvrbQ6E/0)

Comment: This works perfectly on the numeric value items but the sum () function does not work on the alpha values```case when Variable = '%PurchaseOrder' then VarAlphaValue  end AS [Purchase Order],```